# pvcreate not able to initialize physical volume

Tags: lvm

I got some application which will call the pvcreate each time.

I can see the volumes in my vm as follow:

$ pvscan

```
  PV /dev/vda5   VG ubuntu-vg       lvm2 [99.52 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 1 [99.52 GiB] / in use: 1 [99.52 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

$ pvcreate --metadatasize=128M --dataalignment=256K '/dev/vda5'

```
Can't initialize physical volume "/dev/vda5" of volume group "ubuntu-vg" without -ff
```

$ pvcreate --metadatasize=128M --dataalignment=256K '/dev/vda5' -ff

```
Really INITIALIZE physical volume "/dev/vda5" of volume group "ubuntu-vg" [y/n]? y
  Can't open /dev/vda5 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
```

I have also tried wipsfs and observed the same result for above commands

$ wipefs -af /dev/vda5

```
/dev/vda5: 8 bytes were erased at offset 0x00000218 (LVM2_member): 4c 56 4d 32 20 30 30 31
```

How can I execute pvcreate?
Anything to be added for my vm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your hdd (/dev/vda5) is already been used in your `ubuntu-vg`. I think you can not use same hdd partition in 2 different PV's. or you can not add it again.